# Copy Test Cases from one project to another in TestLink

Tags: testlink

I have a scenario , where I need to move the test cases of one project (Say Project 1) to another project (Project 2). Can anyone help me on how to move them?

Can anyone suggest any way of doing this, even if it is possible from Backend?

Comment: @khubhoo, Did you find any resolution for above query I am facing same trouble?

Comment: When you Export the test cases just unselect the "Export Test Case external ID"

Comment: you have two ways, the first one is using 'Create from existing Test Project?' option while creating a new project; the second one is exporting the test cases as XML and import to the new project

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to export the test suite from Project 1 as an XML file. And import the XML file Test suite to the Project 2. You will find test cases in the Project 2.  I suggest you to read the [this official document](http://demo.testlink.org/latest//docs/tl-file-formats.pdf) about how to import/export test cases.

**Update**: As you are importing test cases with the same External ID's, try to remove external ID tags from exported XML. External ID is the generated number of TC visible in Testlink.

Comment: Actually I tried this way. I exported first and then imported .But it is showing me error : : Can not be imported - You are hitting an existent Test Case with SAME EXTERNAL ID . So can you please help me , why i am getting this error?

Comment: @khushboo which version of TestLink do you use?  This issue was fixed in v1.9.8 (http://mantis.testlink.org/view.php?id=5812)

Comment: I am Using 1.9.12